# Cordova Social Sharing

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2

I am using the cordova social sharing plugin. 
Here is my code.

```
  public shareTo(): void {
    var options = {
      message: 'Check out this item',
      subject: 'Item',
      url: 'http://example.com',
      chooserTitle: 'Share via...'
    };
    SocialSharing.shareWithOptions(options);
    console.log(options);
  }
```

I want to be able to change the url to the selected item url from the database. For example...

```
url: item.url
```

This is my html button.

```
<button ion-button (click)="shareTo()">
```

So when someone clicks to share, the url changes to the url of the selected item url. However, I am wondering if this is possible with shareWithOptions or not.

Comment: Well, yes. `url: item.url` will work if it is a `string` and is in the form of `http://example.com/item/3` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

Yes it's possible.

**Longer answer:**

I'll discuss 2 scenario's, with and without a list. The scenario's are taking into account that the `item` *must be defined and must be a string in the form of `http://example.com/item/3`*

---

**Scenario 1**, on a detail page with a property `item`

This scenario requires a property called `item` in your class. (so f.e. `let item: { url: 'someUrl'}; constructor(){ ... }`)

If you're on a detail page with no list assosciated to items. (you basically provided the answer yourself to this one)

```
<button ion-button (click)="shareTo()">
```

And the `ts`

```
public shareTo(): void {
    var options = {
      message: 'Check out this item',
      subject: 'Item',
      url: item.url, //the property mentioned in the explanation
      chooserTitle: 'Share via...'
    };
    SocialSharing.shareWithOptions(options);
    console.log(options);
  }
```

---

**Scenario 2**, on a list page

let's consider you're having a list of items, called `itemList`. Now you want to be able to share any of these from the same page you're in now.

The html would be something like (notice the item object passed in the method)

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemList" (click)="shareTo(item)">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

Typescript could then be kept the same as above, just add in a parameter.

```
public shareTo(item: any): void {
    var options = {
      message: 'Check out this item',
      subject: 'Item',
      url: item.url, //the paramater
      chooserTitle: 'Share via...'
    };
    SocialSharing.shareWithOptions(options);
    console.log(options);
  }
```

---

You're basically constructing an `[Object]` with the properties `message`, `subject`, `url` and `chooserTitle` so there's no reason this shouldn't be able to work.

Comment: Wanted the Scenario 2.  It works as I wanted. Thank you very much for you answer.